# How to Configure MR1 on CDH5.1 vm

Tags: hadoop, cloudera-cdh

I have installed CDH5.1 VM  on my machine. CDH 5.1 is by default set to MR2(YARN). I would want to change the configuration from MR2 to MR1. Request to let me know the changes that need to be done.

Answer (score 0):

Just do the steps to set MR configuration as given in the cdh5.1.2 Documentation

http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH5/latest/CDH5-Installation-Guide/cdh5ig_mr_cluster_deploy.html#topic_11_3

then use the hadoop command and not he yarn command to run the jar